# Download PDF from a URL in Downloads folder on android app with targetSdkVersion=30

Tags: android, android-11, android-storage

I want to download a pdf from a url on Android>=11. My app is targeting android version 30.

I read that due to restrictions introduced from Android 11, it does not easily allow us to store files in external Downloads folder and we have to store it inside Android/package_name/[folder]/[file], but I want to store it in Downloads folder so that my user does not have to go inside Android/package/[Downloads]/[file] to view that file.

Also on devices which are running Android<11, I can download that file by simply using getExternalStorageDirectory right? Please provide me some clarity on this.

I found some answers previously but they weren't that helpful. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Would be better if you can tell me how instead of telling it's too easy for you. I am a beginner.

Comment: Can you please provide some code sample as an answer instead of writing "use same code" so that I can know the correct way to do this and if or not I am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 10ff it is not easy to use the java class "File" to store data in a public accessable folder that is pre-defined by your app.(ie the public download folder)

Instead your app has to ask the app-user [where he/she wants to store the document](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file).